# I need to install VS2008, I already have BIDS installed

Tags: visual-studio-2008, bids

Installing VS2008 on a machine with BIDS 2008 already installed, is there any pre-cautions I need to take? Will it give me any problems?

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't have any problems doing this.  I've done it several times and this is the order we used when installing applications for our standard BI developer computer image.  Of course you probably figured this out several months ago now... :P